# Why don't one sided ranges cover all cases in a Swift switch statement?

Tags: swift, switch-statement, range, swift4

In defining an enum of constants, and noticed that when using range operators to cover all possible cases of a given float, the compiler is complaining that it doesn't actually cover all cases.

```
enum Constants: String
{
    case black,
    diamond,
    platinum,
    gold,
    silver

    func floatValue() -> Float
    {
        switch self
        {
        case .black:
            return 0.30
        case .diamond:
            return 0.25
        case .platinum:
            return 0.15
        case .gold:
            return 0.10
        case .silver:
            return 0.05
        }
    }

    init(floatValue: Float)
    {
        switch floatValue //error: Switch must be exhaustive
        {
        case 0.30, 0.30...:
            self = Constants.black
        case 0.25..<0.30:
            self = Constants.diamond
        case 0.15..<0.25:
            self = Constants.platinum
        case 0.10..<0.15:
            self = Constants.gold
        case ..<0.10:
            self = Constants.silver
        }
    }
}
```

As I understand it, the range operators here should cover every possible float value to the greatest possible precision. Am I using them wrong? Or is there something else going on?

Note that this is more of a thought experiment than anything else. Does anyone know why this doesn't work without a default statement?

Comment: You don't cover `NaN` and `-NaN`, but even still, `switch` statement's exhaustivity checks only for enums

Comment: @Alexander This is used in the context of an enum, let me unsimplify the code

Comment: @Alexander NaN and -NaN are allowed to be passed into the constructor? In Swift? I would think that would generate a compiler error

Comment: Note: I'm not talking about `nil`, which would require the parameter type to be `Float?` and wouldn't work. I'm talking about [`Float.nan`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/floatingpoint/1641652-nan).

Comment: I didn't know that existed in Swift.

Comment: Yep. Float/Double are based on the IEEE754 standard, because that's what's implemented in the hardware.